# Why my deeplink don't work anymore when I have more than one host?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-manifest

When I have my deeplink as below defined in AndroidManifest.xml as below

```
            <intent-filter >
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

                <data
                    android:host="example-host"
                    android:scheme="my-app" />

            </intent-filter>
```

I can perform a deeplink using `adb shell am start -d my-app://example-host`

However, after I add another host as below,

```
            <intent-filter >
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

                <data
                    android:host="example-host"
                    android:scheme="my-app" />

                <data
                    android:host="example-host-2"
                    android:pathPattern="/"
                    android:scheme="my-app" />
            </intent-filter>
```

The result is

- the `adb shell am start -d my-app://example-host` don't work anymore
- the `adb shell am start -d my-app://example-host-2/` works.
- the `adb shell am start -d my-app://example-host/` also works.

Why did the `adb shell am start -d my-app://example-host` don't work anymore? A bug in Android?

Answer (score 0):

To workaround this issue, I'll have to split the host with `pathPattern` with the one without in different `intent-filter`

```
            <intent-filter >
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

                <data
                    android:host="example-host"
                    android:scheme="my-app" />

            </intent-filter>

            <intent-filter >
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

                <data
                    android:host="example-host-2"
                    android:pathPattern="/"
                    android:scheme="my-app" />
            </intent-filter>
```

With that, now all works

- the `adb shell am start -d my-app://example-host` works
- the `adb shell am start -d my-app://example-host-2/` works.
- the `adb shell am start -d my-app://example-host/` also works.